# Multer is not working outside of the http object

Tags: node.js, multer

I am using multer and it works fine in the http object, here is the code:

```
server = http.createServer(function(req, res){
  var upload = multer({ storage : multerhelper.storage}).single('userFile');
  upload(req, res, function(err) {
    if(err)
      console.log("Error uploading the file");
  });
});
```

The moment I take this piece of code outside of the http object inside another file, it doesn't work anymore.

```
handlers._users.post = function(req, res, data, callback){
    var upload = multer({ storage : multerhelper.storage}).single('userFile');
    upload(req, res, function(err) {
      if(err)
        console.log("Error uploading the file");
      callback(400, {'Message' : 'Done'});
    });
});
```

Your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a file which will have the multer logic and export this file so that you can get the multer functionality.
example:

```
const multer = require("multer");

// store the file reference through multer 
const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, callback) {
//Where file should be store
    callback(null, __base + "/public/uploads");
  },
  filename: function (req, file, callback) {
    callback(null, file.originalname);
  }
});

//make sure file is image as the jpeg or png
const fileFilter = (req, file, callback) => {
  if (file.mimetype === "image/jpeg" || file.mimetype === "image/png" || file.mimetype === 'application/octet-stream') {
    callback(null, true);
  }
  callback(null, false);
};

export const upload = multer({
  storage,
  limits: {
    fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5000
  },
  fileFilter
});
```

Now import this file as

```
import {
  upload
} from "/filepath";
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt answer, could you please explain how I will use the upload object to upload a file by the name of "userFile"?

Comment: I actually managed to use your code, but the problem persists, it's like the req object doesn't have the file information anymore when it's passed to another function

Comment: You can get the reference from here.
https://github.com/sumitkumar1207/jwt-auth/blob/master/routes/api/images.js